# Implementing Cache in azure service fabrics

Tags: azure, caching, azure-service-fabric

In my previous projects which are monolithic apps we used Redis as distributed cache.

In azure service fabrics we have concept called statefull services is this concept similar to distributed cache like redis or different. Can we create statefull service and use it as cache layer. Can any one guide if i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only makes sense to use reliable collections within the service boundaries because the read/write operations are local IO. It's replicated between service instances so that involves some network traffic between the nodes but it's minimal.  If you are trying to make a stateful service for the only sole purpose of caching data for external services it sort of goes against the best principles and should be similar to Redis in terms of performance (I didn't actually compare the numbers).